# PostgreSQL IN all

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I have the following table structure:

```
| id | object_id | status_id |
------------------------------
| 1  |     12    |     1     |
| 2  |     12    |     2     |
| 3  |     18    |     5     |
```

I need to select all `object_id` that were in status 1 and 2. That is, something like this: `select object_id from table_name where status_id in (1, 2)`, but I need `status_id` to be not in one of the listed values, but exactly in both. That is, from the above table, I should return the value 12 (cause `object_id` in that statuses equals 12). How can this be done?

Comment: Why does it have to be 12? 1 is in the set (1, 2)

Comment: @Andronicus I need to get an `object_id` that has entries with status 1 and 2, so it returns 12. I gave an example with sql `in` for clarity

Comment: Do you want to have those objects that have **exactly** those two status values, or **at least** those two values?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name exactly those two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get those object IDs that have *exactly* those two status values, you can use

```
select object_id
from the_table
group by object_id
having bool_and(status_id in (1,2))
   and count(distinct status_id) = 2
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1ebc8aa076db1829a8fa9bdf2e43f26d)

Answer (score 1):

```
select object_id 
from table_name 
where status_id in (1, 2)
group by object_id 
having count(distinct status_id) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need unique object id from status 1 or 2 then you can use `distinct` keyword.:

```
select distinct object_id from table_name where status_id in (1, 2)
```

Comment: That returns the wrong result https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e39f96636c0b7084afbc659861648d2d

Comment: it returns object_id if status is 1 or two. I mentioned that in my answer. uf desired answer is to have distinct object_id which have both 1 and 2 in status field then group by is a easy solution.